# plsql function must be declared

Tags: sql, plsql

So I have this function called cal_approv that calculates a quantity of supply, by selecting
the sum of ordered quantity, the "present" quantity, and the min quantity of a giving product(idart)...fecthing information into cursor then inserting it into a result table(resultat), when i try to run this code

```
accept idarticle prompt 'Donner lid article : '
declare
FUNCTION cal_approv(code_art article.idart%type)
RETURN number IS qte _app number;
qtot number;
qtestk number;
qtemin number;

begin
select sum(qte_com) into qtot from lig_com where idart=code_art;
select qtestk into qtestk from article where idart=code_art;
select qtemin into qtemin from article where idart=code_art;
if ((qtot/qtestk)>(2*qtemin)) then
    qte_app := qtot-qtestk*1.5;
else 
    qte_app := qtot*1.2;
end if;
return qte_app;
end;
/
drop function cal_approv;
declare
cursor arts is select idart, desart,pu from article where qtestk <= qtemin;
ida number;
da number;
qa number;
pa number;
begin
open arts;
loop
fetch arts into ida, da, pa;
qa :=  cal_ap prov(&idarticle);
pa := pa*cal_approv(&idarticle);
exit when(arts%notfound);
insert into resultat values(ida,da, qa,pa);
end loop;
close arts;
end;
/
select * from resultat;
```

I get this error
`PLS-00201: identifier 'CAL_APPROV' must be declared`

any help is appreciated!

Comment: There seems to be some confusion here.  Firstly, you attempt to create a PL/SQL block with a local function (which exists only inside the anonymous block and won't be available after the block completes), but the body of the block appears to be missing: it needs at least a `begin`  to follow after the function declaration.  I get an error `Encountered the symbol "end-of-file"` running your first block.  If you want to create a new function and be able to use it outside of the block it's declared in, replace `declare` with `create or replace`.

Comment: Secondly, whether you function gets created or not, you then attempt to drop it, and then in your final block you attempt use the dropped function.  You can't call a dropped function because a dropped function no longer exists in the database.  Why drop the function?

Comment: i tried to drop the function to see if it was created, and what saw was that there was no function created !

Comment: and yes, i'm pretty confused, because as i know i can declare a function within the declare block then use just after, that's what i want to do

Comment: Like this : ```DECLARE PROCEDURE affichage IS BEGIN dbms_output.put_line('Bonjour .Nous sommes le ' || to_char(sysdate, 'dd month yyyy')); END; BEGIN affichage; END; / ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I get when I indent your first block of PL/SQL code:

```sql
declare
  FUNCTION cal_approv(code_art article.idart%type)
  RETURN number
  IS
    qte_app number;
    qtot number;
    qtestk number;
    qtemin number;
  begin
    select sum(qte_com) into qtot from lig_com where idart=code_art;
    select qtestk into qtestk from article where idart=code_art;
    select qtemin into qtemin from article where idart=code_art;
    if ((qtot/qtestk)>(2*qtemin)) then
      qte_app := qtot-qtestk*1.5;
    else 
      qte_app := qtot*1.2;
    end if;
    return qte_app;
  end;
/
```

Note that the `end` in the second-last line ends the function, not the anonymous PL/SQL block.  This will cause an error because Oracle is expecting something like the following:

```sql
declare
  FUNCTION cal_approv(code_art article.idart%type)
  RETURN number
  IS
    -- ...
  begin
    -- body of function omitted
  end;
begin
  -- do something with this function
end;
/
```

Also, to be clear, a function declared within a PL/SQL block, rather than with a `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ...` statement, exists only while that block is being executed.  Once the block completes, the function no longer exists.  So you can write the following block:

```sql
DECLARE
  FUNCTION add_one(p_in IN NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN p_in + 1;
  END;
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line(TO_CHAR(add_one(4));
END;
/
```

This should write `5` to `dbms_output`, if that has been enabled.

On the other hand, this won't work:

```sql
DECLARE
  FUNCTION add_one(p_in IN NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN p_in + 1;
  END;
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
/

BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line(TO_CHAR(add_one(4));
END;
/
```

This doesn't work because the function `add_one` is no longer available when the first block completes.  The second block will fail with an error because it cannot find the function `add_one`.

There is no point attempting to use `DROP FUNCTION` with your function.  `DROP FUNCTION` can only drop stored functions, and because your function is declared within a PL/SQL block, it is not a stored function.

As I see it you have two alternatives:

- declare the function as a stored function, using `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ...`, outside of any `DECLARE` block, or
- move all of the code that uses the function into the same block that declares the function.

In the latter case, your code would look something like the following (abbreviated for clarity):

```sql
declare
  FUNCTION cal_approv(code_art article.idart%type)
  RETURN number
  IS
    -- ...
  begin
    -- ...
  end;

  cursor arts is select idart, desart,pu from article where qtestk <= qtemin;
  ida number;
  da number;
  qa number;
  pa number;
begin
  open arts;
  loop
    -- ...
  end loop;
  close arts;
end;
/
```

Comment: yup, that's what i want, the latter solution, but it won't work for me, this is the block of code m trying after some changes, it looks like the problem isn't with the function but the cursor

Comment: @SafwenSoker: please don't post your code as a series of comments.  If you need further help figuring out the problem with the cursor, please ask a separate question, as this question is focused on the 'function must be declared' error.

Comment: should i delete them ?

Comment: @SafwenSoker: yes, please delete your two code comments on this answer.